# Why is this button appearing in all UITextField selections?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a UITableViewCell with a text field that's supposed to be for a DatePicker. I need to make a custom button to save the date. But whenever I select any of the UITableViewCell TextFields, the button appears. Why is this?

I'm just trying to "submit" it to the text field so I can save it.

Thanks

```
    - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)dateFieldText
{    

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Save Date"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(flipView)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.dateFieldText setInputView:datePicker];


}
```

**Update**

Solved my problem using if else block.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    sender.delegate = self;
        if([sender isEqual:dateFieldText])
        {
            UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                           initWithTitle:@"Save"
                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                           target:self
                                           action:@selector(saveDate)];
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
            UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
            datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
            [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [self.dateFieldText setInputView:datePicker];
        }
        else{
            UIBarButtonItem *submitButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                           initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                           target:self
                                           action:@selector(submitList)];
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = submitButton;
        }  
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: because the method is, "textFieldDidBeginEditing:". You have made self as the delegate of all the cell textfields. That's it adds button when you start typing in a text field

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    sender.delegate = self;
        if([sender isEqual:dateFieldText])
        {
            UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                           initWithTitle:@"Save"
                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                           target:self
                                           action:@selector(saveDate)];
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
            UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
            datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
            [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [self.dateFieldText setInputView:datePicker];
        }
        else{
            UIBarButtonItem *submitButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                           initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                           target:self
                                           action:@selector(submitList)];
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = submitButton;
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you reusing table view cells? You might consider making a new cell for your date field and giving it a different reuse identifier from your other cells.

Comment: No I'm not. But isn't that what dateFieldText is for?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the dataPicker to the intended TextField only i.e you should add an if condition to add the datePicker to the required field only, not for all the fields.